# Automatically add python objects to a dictionary

Tags: python, class, object, dictionary

I have a class containing information used elsewhere in the program with many many instances being defined. I want to add all of these to a dictionary with their name property as the key (see below), so the user can access them.

Because I am frequently making new such objects, is there any way to automatically have them added to the dictionary in the same way? Or of course to a list that I could then iterate over to add to the dictionary afterwards.

Simplified example:

```
class Example:
    def __init__(self, name, eg):
        self.name = name 
        self.eg = eg

a = Example("a", 0)
b = Example("b", 1)
c = Example("c", 2)
# etc...

# Adding to this dictionary is what I'd like to automate when new objects are defined
examples = {a.name : a,
            b.name : b,
            c.name : c,
            # etc...
            }

# User choice
chosen_name = raw_input("Enter eg name: ")
chosen_example = examples[chosen_name]

# Do something with chosen_example . . .
```

I'm familiar with python but haven't done much with classes so I'm not sure what's possible. Alternative approaches with similar results would also be great, thanks in advance!

Comment: Just add `examples[self.name] = self` in the constructor...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below sample should be what you need.

In `__init__`, save your object to class variables=`Example._ALL_EXAMPLES`, then you can access it by `Example._ALL_EXAMPLES` even hasn't created any instance of this class (it returns `{}`).

I think we should avoid using global variables at here, so use class variables will be better.

```
class Example:
    _ALL_EXAMPLES = {}
    def __init__(self, name, eg):
        self.name = name
        self.eg = eg
        Example._ALL_EXAMPLES[self.name] = self
print(Example._ALL_EXAMPLES)
a = Example("a", 0)
b = Example("b", 1)
c = Example("c", 2)
# etc...

print(Example._ALL_EXAMPLES)
```

Output:

```
{}
{'a': <__main__.Example object at 0x01556530>, 'b': <__main__.Example object at 0x015564D0>, 'c': <__main__.Example object at 0x01556A50>}
[Finished in 0.163s]
```

Comment: If you don't want to hardcode the class name: `type(self)._ALL_EXAMPLES[...]`

Comment: @VPfB I think it will work only if `_ALL_EXAMPLES` is a int/string/float etc . And I believe this kinds of hardcode will give us a benefit, we can get one default value = {} even hasn't created any instance.

Comment: there is a difference only in subclasses. Iit wasn't specified where instances of subclasses should be registered. Never mind, that was just a remark and your anwser is fine.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I've done in the past is have objects add themselves to a class dictionary:

```
class Example:
    objects = {}

    def __init__(self, name, eg):
        Example.objects[name] = self  # self.objects also works
        ...
...
Example.objects[chosen_name]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can pass the dict to all the objects you create, something like this:

```
class Example:
    def __init__(self, name, eg, all_examples):
        self.name = name 
        self.eg = eg
        all_examples[name] = self

all_examples = {}
a = Example("a", 0, all_examples)
b = Example("b", 1, all_examples)
c = Example("c", 2, all_examples)

print(all_examples)
```